# How to execute query only once in Django?

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-fql

This is the following query that I have in my views.py:

```
#parse json function
parse = get_persistent_graph(request)

#guys
male_pic = parse.fql('SELECT name,uid,education FROM user WHERE sex="male" AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())')
```

This query currently takes approximately 10 seconds for me to load with about 800+ friends.

**Is it possible to only query this once, update when needed and save to a variable to use instead of having to query every time the page is loaded/refreshed?**

Some possible solutions that I can think of are:

- Saving to the database - IMO that doesn't seem easily scaleable if I save every query from every user of this application
- Some function I have no knowledge of
- Improved and more efficient query request

Could someone please guide me to the path gate with the most efficient direction? Hoping I can lower 10 second requests to < 1 second! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cache system for that (like memcache).

Comment: Learn something new everyday! Thank you for the answer and example, just what I need!